# How to retrieve the field name of a ShapeFile feature field?

Tags: ruby, gdal, esri, ogr

I am using [gdal-ruby](https://github.com/zhm/gdal-ruby) to parse [ESRI ShapeFiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) like in this [demo](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/6007016). I want to iterate through all features in order to push the field values into a database. However, I cannot find out how to retrieve the **name of each field** which I need to match the **database column**. By now I can only work with the **field index** of the field such as:

```ruby
dataset = Gdal::Ogr.open(filename)
number_of_layers = dataset.get_layer_count
number_of_layers.times do |layer_index|
  layer = dataset.get_layer(layer_index)
  layer.get_feature_count.times do |feature_index|
    feature = layer.get_feature(feature_index)
    feature.get_field_count.times do |field_index|
      field_value = feature.get_field(field_index)
      # How can I find out the name of the field?
      puts "Value = #{field_value} for unknown field name"
    end
  end
end
```

I checked the available methods with *irb* and looked into the [API documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180722025614/http://www.gdal.org:80/hierarchy.html). It seems as if I am searching for the wrong terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the OGR API itself, I think you need to go via [feature.GetDefnRef](https://web.archive.org/web/20140208234949/http://www.gdal.org:80/ogr/classOGRFeature.html#a01ef8d59265a7ab7a575387a8269bf92), to get the feature definition, then [.GetFieldDefn](https://web.archive.org/web/20131207053241/http://www.gdal.org:80/ogr/classOGRFeatureDefn.html#a43b95ce699bbca73acb453cc959378e7) for the relevant field, and finally [.GetNameRef](https://web.archive.org/web/20140207104831/http://www.gdal.org:80/ogr/classOGRFieldDefn.html#a7754d32a36e4ba854f71f511a5ca7740)...?

```ruby
...
feature.get_field_count.times do |field_index|
  defn_ref = feature.get_defn_ref
  field_defn = defn_ref.get_field_defn(field_index)
  field_name = field_defn.get_name
  field_value = feature.get_field(field_index)
  puts "Value = #{field_value} for field named #{field_name}"
end
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ds = ogr.Open(filename, 1)
layer = ds.GetLayer()

for i in range(len(layer.schema)):
    print(layer.schema[i].name)
```